# Move files recursively to new directory shutil.move

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to move all`.jpg` files, **recursively** from the CWD, into a single new directory. Unable to make `shutil.move` recursive. Any hints in regard of the **last line in the code**?

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

from_dir = input('Enter recursive FROM directory (if CWD, enter .): ')
to_dir = input('Enter TO directory (if CWD, enter .): ')

if not os.path.exists(to_dir):
    os.makedirs(to_dir)

for imagfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(from_dir, "*.jpg")):
    shutil.move(imagfile, to_dir)
```

I tried these, **do not work**:

```
#shutil.move(os.path.join(root, imagfile), os.path.join(to_dir, imagfile))
#shutil.move(from_dir, imagfile, to_dir)
#shutil.move(os.path.join(from_dir, imagfile), to_dir)
#shutil.move(imagfile, to_dir+imagfile)
#shutil.move(from_dir+imagfile, to_dir+imagfile)
```

Comment: just find all .jpg files in root of that folder? or in its subdirs too?

Comment: from the subdirectories too, from the entire tree, recursive, find all "jpg" files in whatever folder they are and simply move to a new folder. like "collecting" all jpg files into one place. if you put a `Warning: duplicate filenames` that would be nice in case the destination folder contains the filename already (only filename match, not actual md5 comparison).

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
import os, time, inspect, shutil

main_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))

from_dir = ""  # write your source dir
to_dir = "" # write your target dir


def check_target():

    global to_dir

    if to_dir.strip() == "":
        print("Plz Insert a Valid 'to_dir' path!")
        exit()

    elif to_dir == ".":
        to_dir = os.path.join(main_path, to_dir)

    elif os.path.exists(to_dir) is True:
        to_dir = os.path.abspath(to_dir)

    else:
        os.mkdir(to_dir)


check_target()


for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(from_dir):

    for items in filenames:

        file_full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, items))

        if file_full_path.lower().endswith(".jpg") or file_full_path.lower().endswith(".jpeg"):

            check_address = os.path.join(to_dir, os.path.basename(file_full_path))

            if os.path.exists(check_address) and os.path.isfile(check_address):

                warning_message = "WARNING Duplicate File Names : {0}".format(check_address)
                print(warning_message)

            else:
                try:
                    shutil.move(file_full_path, check_address)
                except:
                    print("Something Went Wrong On " + file_full_path)

        else:
            pass
```

Good Luck ...

Comment: `line 27, in <module>
    check_target()
line 24, in check_target
    os.mkdir(to_dir)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\TEST\x07\\target_dir'` error.

Comment: @HakariDo: whats your from_dir and to_dir?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can recursively obtain all dir and make shutil.move to every dir。

```
import os

root = "/Users/xyz/Documents/fun/test"
g = os.walk(root)

dirs = []

for i in g:
    dirs.append(i[0])

print(dirs)
```

Comment: How are you suggesting this with shutil.move?  The code does not append dir to filename,

Comment: maybe modify the variable of 'root' to your from_dir?